# Fin scan detected

Tags: anti-virus

I have been using the same computer with the same isp and firewall for quite some time now. However since the past 2 days I kepp getting atleast one alert log telling me that a fin scan is underway. It gives me the remote ip too and the network isnt even on my isp. Why is this happening so often. I am using http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_global

Comment: Some more info would be good: do you have a virusscanner installed ? Malware scanner ? Which one ?

Comment: I am using http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_global

Comment: Please edit your original question to incorporate this information. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly related: http://superuser.com/questions/293642/anti-virus-alert-syn-fin-scan?rq=1

Comment: Checked that already. The remote ip is the local ip.

Comment: Could you post some log entries please ?

Comment: It doesnt say much in the log entry - Only that a fin scan is detected and it gives me the remote as well as local ip of the machine. However I did observe that he above takes place only when skype is running. Extremely similar to http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/Fin-Scan-when-having-Skype-on/td-p/667011

Answer (score 1):

> TCP FIN Scan
>
> Hackers use the TCP FIN scan to identify listening TCP port numbers
>   based on how the target device reacts to a transaction close request
>   for a TCP port (even though no connection may exist before these close
>   requests are made). This type of scan can get through basic firewalls
>   and boundary routers that filter on incoming TCP packets with the
>   Finish (FIN) and ACK flag combination. The TCP packets used in this
>   scan include only the TCP FIN flag setting.
>
> If the target device's TCP port is closed, the target device sends a
>   TCP RST packet in reply. If the target device's TCP port is open, the
>   target device discards the FIN and sends no reply.

Scan your computer for backdoors, as there is a good chance some piece of malware is calling home. [Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) is pretty good. Do a **full scan**.

Comment: I checked a little more and the port is the port on which skype is running and I also observed that this behaviour is shown only when I have skype running. Any ideas why. I did a full scan but it could not find anything